# Receiving "No frames output" when using AndroidSequenceEncoder

Tags: java, android, video, runtime-error

I am trying to use AndroidSequenceEncoder to create a video slideshow. In order to do this, I have a method that retrieves an ArrayList of Bitmaps and a String representing the video's filename. The following is my method's code:

```
public class ImageToVideo
{
    //used to input frames (images) into the video file
    private AndroidSequenceEncoder ase;
    //Arraylist containing the frames to input
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> bi;
    //temporary variable used for AsyncTask below
    private Bitmap image;
    //This method is called until main code can be written to retrieve the proper length of the audio file
    public AndroidSequenceEncoder videoEncode(final ArrayList<Bitmap> images, String filename) throws  IOException
    {
        ase = AndroidSequenceEncoder.createSequenceEncoder(new File(filename), 3);
        bi = images;
        Log.d("SEQUENCEENCODER", "SequenceEncoder created");
        //outer for-loop; goes through each image individually
        for(int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++)
        {
            Log.d("SEQUENCEENCODER", "Retrieving image " + i + " of " + (images.size() - 1));
        //inner for-loop; adds the given image a number of times determined by how long each image is on-screen
        //since encoder's fps is currently set to 3, this loops once for each second the picture should be on-screen times 3
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            Log.d("SEQUENCEENCODER", "Encoding image " + i + ", " + (j+1) + " of " + 3);
            image = bi.get((i));
            //used because of error "Choreographer: Skipped ~90 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread"
            AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ase.encodeImage(image);
                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    ase.finish();
    return ase;
}
```

The AndroidSequenceEncoder's fps is set to 3 as a temporary value; when I work on the code more, I want this method to take the video's length as well, so that the method determines fps based on the how long each image should be on-screen, given they each have equal time. When running this method with 4 images, I get the following messages

```
D/SEQUENCEENCODER: SequenceEncoder created
D/SEQUENCEENCODER: Retrieving image 0 of 3
D/SEQUENCEENCODER: Encoding image 0, 1 of 3
D/SEQUENCEENCODER: Encoding image 0, 2 of 3
D/SEQUENCEENCODER: Encoding image 0, 3 of 3
D/SEQUENCEENCODER: Retrieving image 1 of 3
D/SEQUENCEENCODER: Encoding image 1, 1 of 3
D/SEQUENCEENCODER: Encoding image 1, 2 of 3
D/SEQUENCEENCODER: Encoding image 1, 3 of 3
D/SEQUENCEENCODER: Retrieving image 2 of 3
D/SEQUENCEENCODER: Encoding image 2, 1 of 3
D/SEQUENCEENCODER: Encoding image 2, 2 of 3
D/SEQUENCEENCODER: Encoding image 2, 3 of 3
D/SEQUENCEENCODER: Retrieving image 3 of 3
D/SEQUENCEENCODER: Encoding image 3, 1 of 3
D/SEQUENCEENCODER: Encoding image 3, 2 of 3
D/SEQUENCEENCODER: Encoding image 3, 3 of 3
I/System.out: [WARN]    . (:0): No frames output.
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa8a05240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8a03250)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa8a05240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8a03250)
I/chatty: uid=10080(projectname) RenderThread identical 1 line
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa8a05240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8a03250)
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=122KB, data=94KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=117KB, data=92KB
I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
```

followed by a long list of system errors pointing back to the command

```
ase.encodeImage(image);
```

A new video file does get created in the Android Virtual Device, but it ends almost immediately after playing, despite that it says its length is 4 seconds. I am wondering what I am doing wrong in the code to cause this.

Answer (score 0):

One problem that I see with the above code is that the actual encoding of frames takes place in a separate (background) thread. So under some circumstance it is possible that none of the frames are actually encoded by the time 'finish' is called.
What you need to do is make sure 'finish' is called after the encoding of all frames actually took place. There are multiple ways to achieve this:

1. Move your loops entirely inside the async task followed by finish;
2. In case there's only one executor thread you can get away with executing 'finish' inside the async task also, that way you'll rely on internal executor queue to execute your 'finish' at the very end;
3. Use thread synchronization primitives, like 'wait/notify'. So in the main thread you can 'wait' before calling 'finish' and in the async task you'll 'notify'. Though this is a viable option I would strongly discourage you from using it for a variety of other reasons.